# Is there a React Native framework for basic CRUD tasks?

Tags: react-native, development-environment

I'm looking for a framework/tool which allows me to create a React Native app quickly. My porpouse is to map a data source (usually we work with oData source) and then the framework should be able to create a basic UI which allows me to perform basic CRUD tasks.
If you are familiar with DevExpress [XAF](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112558/fundamentals/xaf-overview) you know what I'm talking about more specifically. 
Can anyone help me?
What I'm loolking for is not a IDE or similar that help with React Native development, but any suggestion is accepted.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of React Native is to give developers the flexibility to build native apps with the absolute basic components. As far as I am aware there is no such tool. The closest you have is React Native Expo. Invest some time and try to understand what React Native is and how it works and what was the idea behind it in the first place.